# How to increase the number of ECS tasks in AWS Event Bridge?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-event-bridge

I'm having this SAA C02 question and I wanted to implement it in AWS.

[image: SAA c02 exam question]
Now when i went to AWS Event Bridge. I did not find how can i make scale in or scale out of ECS tasks.

Here is what i found:
[image: Aws Event Bridge]
My question is how can I put in the event bridge that I want when to increase the number of tasks by 1.Say we have initially 3 tasks and a putObject has been occured .Now we want to add 1 more task .How we can do that in event Bridge?

THanks

Comment: From the Eventbridge console, you can select the desired number of tasks(in the "Count" field) while selecting ECS Task as the target. The answer states the same as to set the desired number of tasks on PUT and to 1 for DELETE. Not "scale up by" say 2 instances

Comment: @ashish.g say for example i received 1 put .So we need to scale out by 1 task.Now if we receive a delete .How can we scale in by 1 (i mean must i put -1 for the delete ?)

Comment: So to delete you have to set the target to 1. So that, if say your cluster is running 4 tasks, it will shut down 3 and the final number of running tasks would be 1. Also, in the case of scale-up, you define target tasks, not the increment.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the AWS blog on filtering s3 events in the event bridge.

> https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-use-amazon-s3-event-notifications-with-amazon-eventbridge/

Create a rule filter to capture delete events and in the target set the count to 1.
The same applies for scaling up creating a rule filter to capture put events from principal "aws.s3" and in the target set the count to the desired scale-up count.